# Firebase DB Update from Background Service

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am seeing a very weird behavior when using updating the Firebase DB from a background service in my Android App. FYI I have SetPersistanceEnabled set to TRUE. My Java API Version is 2.5.0+.

Following is what is happening:

I have a background service started as STICKY. This service receives GCM and on receipt of these messages I do some updates to the Firebase DB. The updates work perfectly fine when the app is running in foreground but as soon as the app is killed the updates are never reflected back to DB online.

I can confirm when App is killed the service restarts itself and also when GCM arrives Firebase UpdateChildren's CompletionListener is called without error which means data has been persisted(I can confirm this based on log statements getting printed on console). But then why I don't see the updates online. I thought because the persistence is enabled it might sync it back once the app again comes online but NO after restarting the app and running it in foreground I still don't see the update getting synced to DB.

Has anyone faced this similar issue. Please let me know if I am doing anything wrong.

BTW I am not using goOnline or goOffline anywhere in the application.

Comment: did you find any solution for this issue I am facing same issue:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37991929/error-on-getting-realtime-database-reference-in-service

Comment: Hi @FarisJameel yes I found the solution for my issue. It was a problem at my end nothing to do with Firebase. Updating Firebase DB from a background IntentService worked all good for me.

Comment: I want to update database from sticky service not from a IntentService

Comment: Can provide log data from android studio

Comment: @SundayGAkinsete here is my question :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37991929/error-on-getting-realtime-database-reference-in-service
you can find my logs on this link question thanks :)

Comment: @FarisJameel using Sticky Service might not be a good idea as it might keep connection to Firebase Servers alive in the background which is not advisable(bad for your mobile battery). In my case I am getting an update in my Sticky Service and I use that update to initiate a IntentService do my work with Firebase. Intent Service shuts down when the job is done.

Comment: @Ato I found my problem and I post answer for my question check it if you want more details about it

Comment: i am facing similar issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40691306/background-service-with-firebase-childeventlistener-not-working-after-few-minute  .No answer yet @ATO will you please provide code how you did by Sticky and intent service. Please any help will be appreciated

Comment: @KarandeepAtwal my service is a simple IntentService which is spawned when I need to update FireBase in background.

Comment: "background service" what do you mean by background service?

Comment: "app is killed" what do you mean by that? app process is killed?

Comment: @MarianPaździoch Background Service means when App is not in foreground and you would like to update Firebase.

Comment: Considering that since Android Oreo this will not be allowed, you might want to change your tactic to Firebase Job Dispatcher https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android

Comment: Yeah agreed. Thanks for the tip @cutiko.

Comment: out of curiosity, why are you using client side dependency when you are doing everything on receiving GCM. I am sure, you can do all these things on server side.

Comment: @ATO Can you please share your working code? I'm having this issue and I don't see anything that is wrong with my end.

Answer (score 0):

this is `FCM`, not `GCM` ...when lacking the `Context` one probably cannot instance the required objects. simply update the records on the server-side - and then update the local version on the next synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to upload to firebase realtime database using this code

```
class MyFirebaseService: FirebaseMessagingService() {

    override fun onMessageReceived(p0: RemoteMessage) {
        FirebaseData().uploadLog("${p0.data}")
    }

}
```