# Error on getting Realtime Database reference in service

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am getting error:

> 06-24 10:41:36.497 17316-17316/com.example.waseem.geolocation:location_service E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                                    Process: com.example.waseem.geolocation:location_service, PID: 17316
>                                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service com.example.waseem.geolocation.LocationService: java.lang.IllegalStateException: FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] doesn't exist. 
>                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3085)
>                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:172)
>                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1505)
>                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
>                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832)
>                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
>                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
>                                                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] doesn't exist. 
>                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                                        at com.example.waseem.geolocation.LocationService.(LocationService.java:34)
>                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
>                                                                                                        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1650)
>                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3082)
>                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:172) 
>                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1505) 
>                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
>                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832) 
>                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399) 
>                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194) `.

on

```
DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

statement in service but its works fine in activity.

Comment: In the lifecycle of your app, when is the service being started? Set your logging level to info and look at the logcat output for "FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful". Does it appear when your app initializes?

Comment: Please post the complete call stack for the exception. Does your app include Firebase Crash Reporting (com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.0.2)?

Comment: @qbix please check updated question I added complete stack of error

Comment: How is the service started?  Using` startService()` in an activity?

Comment: @qbix yes service start with startService() from activity on button click listener

Comment: @qbix and I am using service it's not a intentservice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I Found my problem solution by myself and the issue is I am getting this error because I am running my service in different process that define in manifest where I declare my service:

```
android:process = "......"
```

when I removed it and now my service is running on application main process and I am not getting any error and its works fine.